# Occupy vs. occupying

Tags: ing

Please read the following sentence:

> Determine the mechanism by which the elements occupying the system interact with one another.

Is *occupying* grammatically correct in this context? Should *that occupy* be used instead?

Comment: It is perfectly grammatical and means the exact same thing your alternative does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sentence is correct.

An alternative would be: "Determine the mechanism by which the elements that occupy the system interact with one another."

Comment: Excellent answer DJClayworth, I have voted up; but if you want to attract some other user to do the same, it would be better expand your text saying, for example, which construction is more typical in the English language.